# IIS slow startup when changing physical path

Tags: iis, asp.net

At the moment our deployment process looks like this:

1. Publish site locally in Release mode
2. Zip up and push to a cloud store
3. On production server, pull zipped site down and unzip to new directory
4. Update physical path of site in IIS to point to new path

All in all this works great and lets us iterate often with an easy rollback method (just point IIS to the previous path if an issue is detected). However, when deploying, there is consistently a long lag (~30 secs) once we've switched the physical directory. Some of this is the cold start as it re-reads config files and runs static constructors, but that doesn't explain all of it. On a less used server, the changeover is much faster (~10 secs). I assume it's waiting for existing requests to finish before responding to new ones with the new site path but can't confirm this.

How do we minimize this hanging that users experience when the site has just been switched?

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET Web Application?

Comment: Yes it is an ASP.NET web app.